# Doxygen for qt creator 2.6.81

Tags: qt4, qt-creator, doxygen

There is any Doxygen version that works with Qt creator 2.6.81?

- I have built Qt 4.8.4 (mingw-builds 64bit) and Qt creator 2.6.81

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried Qt creator but I would be surprised if there is a version of doxygen that doesn't work...

Comment: I worked with doxygen with older Qtcreator versions, but it's seems to be that the newset doxygen won't work with the above Qtcreator I have, so I ask if someone know how to make it work with my qt version.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you explain in more detail what "doesn't work" means... what do you see? what do you expect? are there any error messages? how can someone reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have compiled Doxygen source (needed to fix few code in some of the cpp files, so it will work with Qt 4.8.4 code), but when trying to use the plugin in QtCreator, the Doxygen options do nothing...Maybe someone here compiled Doxygen source with a newest Qt and have a good Dll he can send me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Doxygen in `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS`. In your `.pro` fle, write this :

```
gendoc.target = gendoc
gendoc.command = doxygen doxygenfile.sthg
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += gendoc
```

If you want to generate your documentation, use the makefile target that you have created with these 3 lines.

```
make gendoc
```

You can also do this with a custom build configuration (in the "Projects" tab of Qt Creator) and use it with Qt Creator :

[image: Build configuration for generating documentation]

Doxygen and Qt Creator are independant in these case so it should work.